# Viewer: check filetype

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im working with the Forge React viewer.
We are currently getting the filetype before loading files into the viewer from our JSTree and store in the client.
I was wondering if there is a native way within the viewer to get the filetype of a loaded model?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know the file extension of the source model after translating it to svf/svf2. So, you can see that in this way:

```js
let model = viewer.model;

let fileExtension = model.getData()?.loadOptions?.fileExt;
```

here is an example: https://gist.github.com/yiskang/b1f68f5f4b8e4b8d420b6b64e95c48ac